# apache cross domain configuration

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I am trying to setup this application on my server  [openspeedtest.com self-hosted app](http://openspeedtest.com/speed-testing-application-for-your-website.php)
they provided Nginx configuration. how can i make this work on my apache shared hosting server?

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 360;
client_max_body_size 2000M;
location / {
    if ($http_origin) {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://openspeedtest.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

          }
if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://openspeedtest.com";        
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS";
        return 204;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your server!

Setting CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) on Apache. Create .htacess file with this config.

```
# Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://openspeedtest.com"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
#Don't forget to activate the apache module headers a2enmod headers
```